# Do something right before orientation change Javascript or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, orientation

I need to save the KineticJS stage content to session right before orientation change. Is there any event to do this just before changing the orientation using Javascript or JQuery?

Thanks,

Comment: Stop and think about it! How can there even be such an event?

Comment: Then is there any way to achieve this. That is, save stage content to session and just after the orientation is changed, reload the page and set the content from session back.

Comment: why would you need to reload page on change of orientation?

Comment: There is an issue related to the KineticJS stage resizing. On orientation change is not resizing as expected. So we finally came to a solution of saving it just before orientation change and after orientation change reload page and set contents back. Hoping that this will work as expected.

Comment: Why reload whole page and not just rebuild the element(s)?